# Async Task Replacement

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

What is the replacement of async task as it is deprecated and how to use the replacement ? any suggestions.

Replacement that functions same as async task.

Comment: Use coroutines.

Answer (score 0):

Async task is for background operation.

If you want to replace the async task as it is deprecated,
A better option is to use Kotlin Coroutines.

**Kotlin Coroutines:**

1. Coroutines are Kotlin features that allow you to surround your blocking calls(Synchronous) codes in non-blocking(Asynchronous) constructs.
2. A coroutine is like a function or a call which by default runs Asynchronously in parallel with others.
3. Performing Asynchronously task using many other background concepts as mentioned earlier, required a lot of code to write. However, using Coroutines we can write clean and less code.
4. Coroutines look exactly like regular blocking code. But it’s unblocking and lets you write short and understandable code.